# How to insert row at end of table with HTMLTableElement.insertRow

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

#### Background and Setup

I'm trying to create a table from tabular data in javascript, but when I try inserting rows into a table element, it inserts in the opposite order from what I expect and the opposite order of what you get from using `appendChild`. (Here's [a jsfiddle with a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jtratner/9uA9k/) of this).

Say I have some data like this:

```js
var data = [
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
    {"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6},
    {"a": 7, "b": 8, "c": 9}
], keys = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

If I try using the `insertRow()` and `insertCell()` methods for creating tables, iterating over the data and keys above. I get the reverse order of what I expect:

[image: InsertRows pic]

Generated by using the following code:

```js
// insert a table into the DOM
var insertTable = insertDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("table")),
    thead = insertTable.createTHead(), // thead element
    thRow = thead.insertRow(), // trow element
    tbody = insertTable.createTBody(); // tbody element


thRow.insertCell().innerText = "#"; // add row header

// insert columns
for (var i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i ++) {
    var k = keys[i];
    thRow.insertCell().innerText = k;
}

// insert rows of data
for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i ++) {
    var rowData = data[i],
        row = tbody.insertRow();
    row.insertCell().innerText = i;
    for (var j = 0, l = keys.length; j < l; j ++) {
        var elem = rowData[keys[j]];
        row.insertCell().innerText = elem;
    }
}
```

Whereas, if I create a table using `document.createElement` and `appendChild`, I get the order I would expect:

[image: AppendChild pic]

Generated by:

```js
// now do the same thing, but using appendChild
var byChildTable = document.createElement("table");
byChildTable.setAttribute("class", "table");
thead = byChildTable.appendChild(document.createElement("thead"));
thRow = thead.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));

// create table header
thRow.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).innerText = "#";
for (var i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i ++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    thRow.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).innerText = key;
}

// insert table data by row
tbody = byChildTable.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));
for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i ++) {
    var rowData = data[i],
        row = tbody.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
    row.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).innerText = i;
    for (var j = 0, l = keys.length; j < l; j ++) {
        var elem = rowData[keys[j]];
        row.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).innerText = elem;
    }
}
```

#### Question

How do I control the order it puts the elements in the DOM? Is there any way to change this? I guess otherwise I could iterate in reverse order, but even that way, you still can't insert with `table.insertRow()`. It's just a bummer because the `insertRow()` and `insertCell()` methods seem much clearer than `table.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"))` etc.

Comment: `insertRow()` Takes an index as an argument so you can choose where to place the newly inserted row. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/table.insertRow

Comment: wow - I feel a bit silly about that now - I guess I just missed that on MDN. Thanks all!

Comment: FYI, some of the methods you're using don't work in Firefox. I think you'll need `.appendChild()` instead of `.createTBody()` and `.createTHead()`. Also, Firefox will throw an error if you don't include the index in the `insertCell()` and `.insertRow()`.

Comment: @amnotiam thanks, good to know. Apparently the `appendChild` method is faster too.

Comment: @JeffTratner: You're welcome. Also, Firefox doesn't honor the non-standard `.innerText`. The standard property is `.textContent`. IE8 and lower need `.innerText`, so if you support those browsers, I would make a variable like this at the top of your application: `var text = ("textContent" in document) ? "textContent" : "innerText";`, and then use it to get and set text. `row.insertCell(-1)[text] = k;` Here's a full working version: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfqRu/

Comment: @amnotiam thanks for the tip--that's really helpful to know for the future!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `.insertRow` and `.insertCell` methods take an index. In absence of the index, the default value is `-1` in most browsers, however some browsers may use `0` or may throw an error, so it's best to provide this explicitly.

To to an append instead, just provide `-1`, and an append will be done

```
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/table.insertRow

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
var table = document.getElementById('myTableId');
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify an index in `insertCell()` like `insertCell(inde)` in order to work as you expect.

As it is said in [www.w3schools.com/jsref](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_tablerow_insertcell.asp)

> If this parameter is omitted, insertCell() inserts the new cell at the
>   last position in IE and at the first position in Chrome and Safari.
>
> This parameter is required in Firefox and Opera, but optional  in
>   Internet Explorer, Chrome and Safari.

An index is required also in `inserRow()` for the same reason.

Comment: @vortex7: FYI, to highlight documentation, use the *blockquote* formatting instead of the code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this,

```
var table = document.getElementById("yourTable");
var row = table.insertRow(-1);

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
```