# How to add new row in table auto onchange?

Tags: html

It's add row in first row table
I want add to last of rows

```
<script>
function addfunction(){
  var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
  var row = table.insertRow(2);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

  cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='number' disabled>";
  cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='number' name='price'>";
  cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='number' name='count'>";
  cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='text' disabled>";
  cell5.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='barcode' onChange='addfunction()'>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333427/how-to-insert-row-in-html-table-body-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert row at end of table with HTMLTableElement.insertRow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866451/how-to-insert-row-at-end-of-table-with-htmltableelement-insertrow)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions like this often have an answer already, try checking this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15866688/425313